# How to listen on both chat and calling connectors when bot deployed as Azure function

Tags: node.js, azure, botframework

I'm trying to build a bot that supports skype calling in NodeJS and deploy on Azure. However, the example code demonstrating listening on both chat and calling connectors seems to assume that you are running locally and using ngrok to make your bot internet accessible.

For example:

```
var server = restify.createServer();
server.listen(process.env.port || process.env.PORT || 3978, function () {
   console.log('%s listening to %s', server.name, server.url); 
});

// Create chat bot
var chatConnector = new builder.ChatConnector({
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var chatBot = new builder.UniversalBot(chatConnector);
server.post('/api/messages', chatConnector.listen());

// Create calling bot
var connector = new calling.CallConnector({
    callbackUrl: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
    appId: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_ID,
    appPassword: process.env.MICROSOFT_APP_PASSWORD
});
var bot = new calling.UniversalCallBot(connector);
server.post('/api/calls', connector.listen());
```

There are some examples that work on Azure, such as:

```
var connector = useEmulator ? new builder.ChatConnector() : new botbuilder_azure.BotServiceConnector({
    appId: process.env['MicrosoftAppId'],
    appPassword: process.env['MicrosoftAppPassword'],
    stateEndpoint: process.env['BotStateEndpoint'],
    openIdMetadata: process.env['BotOpenIdMetadata']
});

if (useEmulator) {
    var restify = require('restify');
    var server = restify.createServer();
    server.listen(3978, function() {
        console.log('test bot endpont at http://localhost:3978/api/messages');
    });
    server.post('/api/messages', connector.listen());    
} else {
    module.exports = { default: connector.listen() }
    console.log("Running in Azure");
}
```

but it's not clear to me how this would work when I need to listen on two connectors. Is it possible to get this to work? If so what do I need to set in module.exports?

Comment: Why are you saying that the first code assumes you are running locally? The ChatConnector works fine in Azure.

Comment: @EzequielJadib I know the chat connector works in Azure. I have the second example running in Azure. However the first example with two connectors depends on running a restify server and it's not clear to me how to translate into a deployment on Azure which by default if you add a bot service deploys your code as an Azure function (ie Azure listens for HTTP requests).

Comment: That's only true if you use Azure Bot Service. But you can deploy your bot as an Azure web app. Most of these samples have a Deploy to Azure button and they are deployed in a Web App not in a Function. https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder-Samples/tree/master/Node

Comment: Changed title to indicate that I'm interested in deployed as Azure function, rather than web app since deployment as a function seems to be the default when you create a new bot service in Azure.

Comment: But are you creating your bot offline or are you creating the bot via the Azure Portal?

Comment: @EzequielJadib I'm creating the bot via the Azure portal